# Best way to upload gzip file to S3 bucket with boto3

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, gzip, boto3

I have a large pandas dataframe that I gzipped and want to upload to an s3 bucket.

What is the best way to do so?
Using s3_client.upload_file? or bucket.upload_fileobj?
Ive seen a bunch of solutions but cant understand the best manner.
edit: it is in json format
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can write it using several formats. which format you want to use? (csv,json..)?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a one liner that assume csv is the format and [s3fs](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/) is installed.

```
df.to_csv('s3://my_bucket/my_file.csv', compression='zip' )
```